# Is it possible to override a SerializerMethodField for an inherited Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to override a SerializerMethodField from an inherited Serializer?

E.g.

```
# serializers.py

class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["pk", "custom"]

    def get_custom(self, obj):
        return "Base";

class ExtendedSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    custom = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["pk", "custom"]

    def get_custom(self, obj):
        return "Extended";
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work.

I've currently had to create another Serializer and declare a new SerializerMethodField for the inheriting Serializers:

```
# serializers.py

class DefaultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["pk"]


class BaseSerializer(DefaultSerializer):
    custom = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["pk", "custom"]

    def get_custom(self, obj):
        return "Base";

class ExtendedSerializer(DefaultSerializer):
    custom = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["pk", "custom"]

    def get_custom(self, obj):
        return "Extended";
```

But it would be neater for my use case if I could just override an existing SerializerMethodField as in my first code block.

Comment: Normally just overriding the `get_custom` should be sufficient, so not even specifying a new `custom` is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact your proposed solution works, and can be further minimized to:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class DefaultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['pk']

class BaseSerializer(DefaultSerializer):
    custom = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['pk', 'custom']

    def get_custom(self, obj):
        return 'Base'

class ExtendedSerializer(BaseSerializer):

    def get_custom(self, obj):
        return 'Extended'
```

You thus need to mention the `custom` field as a `SerializerMethodField` only *once* in the `BaseSerializer`. By simply overriding the implementation of `get_custom`, it will produce data where the `custom` key is `'Base'`  if serialized by the `BaseSerializer`, and `'Extended'` if serialized by the `ExtendedSerializer`.

Indeed, if we serialize instances, we get:

```
>>> BaseSerializer(Item.objects.first()).data
{'pk': 1, 'custom': 'Base'}
>>> ExtendedSerializer(Item.objects.first()).data
{'pk': 1, 'custom': 'Extended'}
```